A bunch of grammas
On a remote Greek island there was a small community, populated completely by twenty-four grandmothers—indeed it was named after the first two grammas (as they called one another) to join. Each gramma had her own collection of characteristics.

Five of the grammas were always concerned with when someone was going to arrive.
Ten other grammas were selfish—not team players.
Five others had drinking problems but were trying to deal with them.
The remaining four tried to speak some English together every day, although they barely knew one word between them.

What time of day did these last four grammas get together to talk?

These "grammas"

 or rather, *γράμμα*s, are the letters of the Greek alphabet! (Named, of course, after alpha and beta.)

The five who were "always concerned with when someone was going to arrive"

 are worried about ETA: that's beta, delta, zeta, eta, and theta.

The ten who were "not team players"

 have I in them: that's epsilon, iota, xi, omicron, pi, sigma, upsilon, phi, chi, and psii.

(Past this point, I'm not 100% sure this works... there could be a mistake in the question, or I could be misinterpreting something.)
The five with "drinking problems"

 were attending AA meetings: that's alpha, gamma, kappa, lambda. (I think "tau" should be in this set as well, though I'm not entirely sure why.)

This leaves the remaining four,

 mu, omega, rho, and nu, which meet in the MORN!


Great job, exactly right!—despite me making a mistake which you noted as a confusion. rot13(Jura V jnf pbhagvat gur barf gung unq 'nn' ohg abg 'rgn' va gurz, V raqrq hc pbhagvat gur barf gung unq na 'n' gung jnfa'g gur svany yrggre—ohg gung'f n zvfgnxr sbe 'gnh'.)
